# Doctrine does not map correctly relations

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an entity that contains a OneToOne relationship with another entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tb_promocao")
 */
class Promocao {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $codigo;

       /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Model\Produto\Produto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cod_produto", referencedColumnName="codigo")
     */
    private $produto;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tb_produto")
 */
class Produto {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $codigo;

        (...)

}
```

The problem is that when I try to give a fetch entity in Promocao the property $produto is not correctly populated with the Produto entity.

The Produto entity is not properly mapped on the property that receives the relationship.

> Object of: EntityProxy__CG__\Application\Model\Produto\Produto

Comment: Try running the schema-check `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema`

Answer (score 1):

This is normal operation. Your joined model is lazy load so while you don't call it, you will only have a proxy.

You can modify the type of loading joined model setting it to EAGER mode :

```
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Model\Produto\Produto")
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cod_produto", referencedColumnName="codigo", **fetch='EAGER'**)
```

But it's not really recommanded here except if you need this joined data everytimes.

Check Doctrine documentation, there are a lot of precisions about this.

Hope this helps.